# Protractor Typescript: Sudden errors in spec file. Cannot run file

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I was trying to run my sample typescirpt file.  I had successfully converted the .ts file to a js file.   Then I noticed I then got an error in my original TS file which was correct.  Plus I cannot run these spec files.

Not sure what I did wrong.

**How do I fix this?**

Please [watch this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6tg8ko26m195t5/Errors%20in%20spec%20file.mp4?dl=0)

I will also attach the ts. and converted js. files.

I am utterly confused

thanks in advance

**TS. File 1 Sample test file**

```
import{browser} from "protractor";
import{element,by,} from "protractor";


describe('Using chain loctor',function(){


    it('Opening google page',function(){
    // write your code here!!!

        browser.get("http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/");

        element(by.model("first")).sendKeys("3");
        element(by.model("second")).sendKeys("5");

        element(by.id("gobutton")).click();


        //repeater syntax , chaining locators and CSS tags 
        element(by.repeater("result in memory")).element(by.css("td:nth-child(3)")).getText().then(function(text)
                {
            //possible promise syntax here!!!
            console.log(text);


        })
```

**TS. Configuration file**

```
import {Config} from "protractor";

// An example configuration file

export let config: Config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  directConnect:true,


    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome'
    },

    // Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed
    // to protractor (in this example conf.js).
    // They may include glob patterns.
    specs: ['ChaLoctestscript.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
    }
  };
```

3. Converted ts to Javascript Testfile.

This is file I converted in number 1 to javascript

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const protractor_1 = require("protractor");
const protractor_2 = require("protractor");
describe('Using chain loctor', function () {
    it('Opening google page', function () {
        // write your code here!!!
        protractor_1.browser.get("http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/");
        protractor_2.element(protractor_2.by.model("first")).sendKeys("3");
        protractor_2.element(protractor_2.by.model("second")).sendKeys("5");
        protractor_2.element(protractor_2.by.id("gobutton")).click();
        //repeater syntax , chaining locators and CSS tags 
        protractor_2.element(protractor_2.by.repeater("result in memory")).element(protractor_2.by.css("td:nth-child(3)")).getText().then(function (text) {
            //possible promise syntax here!!!
            console.log(text);
        });
    });
});
```

4. The ts. to Javascript Configuration file

The converted configuration file.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
// An example configuration file
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    directConnect: true,
    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    // Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed
    // to protractor (in this example conf.js).
    // They may include glob patterns.
    specs: ['ChaLoctestscript.ts'],
    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
    }
};
```

Finally, the Error message from the terminal.  Sorry for all the code...just trying to be through

**5. Terminal Error message**

```
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/usr/local"
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v11.1.0 --silent` to unset it.Jacquelines-MacBook-Air:ProtractorTypeScriptCucumber jacquelinegeorge$ npm install -g typscrtipt
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: typscrtipt@latest
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacquelinegeorge/.npm/_logs/2019-03-21T11_40_22_316Z-debug.logJacquelines-MacBook-Air:ProtractorTypeScriptCucumber jacquelinegeorge$ npm install -g typescript
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modulesnpm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
Jacquelines-MacBook-Air:ProtractorTypeScriptCucumber jacquelinegeorge$ npm install -g typescript
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
Jacquelines-MacBook-Air:ProtractorTypeScriptCucumber jacquelinegeorge$ npm install -g typescript
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
Jacquelines-MacBook-Air:ProtractorTypeScriptCucumber jacquelinegeorge$ npm install -g typescript
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
```

Comment: Are you sure your error message is related to your e2e tests? The error message shows it failed on `npm install -g typescript` which results in a permission denied error.

Comment: @Mathyn  If it is an issue with typescript. How do I fix it?

Comment: This is not an issue with Typescript but rather a result of an operation trying to write where it has no permission to write. You could try executing this command with `sudo` prepended to it e.g. `sudo npm install -g typescript`. This will execute the command with root access.

Comment: To be honest though you should not have to install global packages with `sudo` if NPM is correctly configured. I see in your error message you also use `nvm` which should allow you to install packages globally without `sudo`. Something tells me your NPM/Node setup is flawed.

Comment: @Mathyn  is there a way I can fix the NPM/Node set up

Comment: it is quite hard to say because I cannot look at your system. You might try completely removing Node/NPM and reinstalling them. However if this is too much of a hassle you can also just use `sudo` for now.

Comment: Ok, I realised what I had done wrong.  It was running visual studio from downloads (I thought I had moved it to applications folder..but hadn't).  sudo worked perfectly once it was moved

Comment: `typscrtipt` => `typescript` The error message shows that there is an incorrect spelling of typescript somewhere. **edit:** you should not include the *first* time you tried to install typescript and mis-typed it.